# Android homescreen widget adding view attribute results in widget not being able to load

Tags: android, xml, flutter, android-layout

I am really confused here. I have a flutter app and it has an android home screen widget. Inside a linear layout I have image, view and text. Now I want basically unlimited space between image and text so they are both at the ends of the parent. So one on left side and one on right side. So I tried to use view in between with weight. The android studio design view shows the space. But when I run the app the widget says "Problem loading widget". Please tell me how to fix this or give an alternative way to achieve this.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_current" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/onethird"
        android:text="1/3 time: 02:04 AM"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Without <View it runs fine but the widgets are beside each other.

Answer (score 0):

@1210saad You must have to add `layout_height` to `View`.